# I keep getting error when I generate apk file but works when I run the program

Tags: android, sdk

This is the error:

Note that these strings can lead to crashes if the string is looked up on
   any locale not providing a translation, so it's important to clean them
   up.

657 errors, 0 warnings

Gradle build finished with 657 error(s) and 10 warning(s) in 4h 33m 28s 959ms

Any idea why this might?

Comment: are you trying to translate your app to another language or locale?

Comment: Yes into different language

Answer (score 0):

Okey... then I think the error is in your string.xml...

you have to include all strings in your string.xml and string-xx.xml..
Even if you are not translating all strings, you have to keep the string in both xml files...
Hope you got me...